# Setting a bit in MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, mips, bit

I am working on setting bits in MIPS, and I have been trying for hours to figure out how to have my code work, but am still lost.

I am trying to create a set0 function that will take in an argument, and then set the 0 bit to 1. I believe I am supposed to use an ori instruction, but I don't know what to put as the last value.

So far I have:

```
set0:

ori $v0, $a0, 0

jr $ra
```

(Which is obviously wrong.)

Any suggestions on how to go about this will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why it should be a 1 and not a 0?? I'm perplexed as to why it's a 1 if the goal is to set the 0 bit.

My apologies, I am awful at MIPS, and I just don't follow the logic for it well at all.

Comment: What's the value of an integer with only the bottom bit set? `ori` sets a register to another register 'logical or' an immediate value. So you need to choose an immediate value that has the bottom bit set. in other words, the value is used to do a logical or with the entire value of the register. The argument does not specify the index of a bit to operate on.

Comment: Oh! I think I understand now.. so the immediate value is used directly in the logical statement, not as an index of where the logical statement should be done.

Comment: @sabrina, yes, exactly.

Comment: Be aware however, that the immediate is 16-bit only. If you want to do bitops on the high 16-bits of a 32-bit register, this approach won't work.